# Show only Parameter selection options in Winforms ReportViewer Control

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using ReportViewer control to display SSRS reports from a report server. Is there any way I can make the viewer control display only the parameter selection portion of the report and not the report itself?

I need to let the user only select the parameters and not see the report that it is a part of.

For example, if this is the report,
[Sample SSRS Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haDws.png) , then I need the ReportViewer Control to display only the part encircled in blue. Basically, the actual report part needs to be hidden and only the options to select the parameters must be shown.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have added an image, hope it is clearer now! :)

Comment: Are you still having an issue with this?

Comment: Yes, have not been able to implement this. But the requirements have changed since then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden parameter to change the visibility of the tablix.

[image]

[image]